# Android How to launch Google + Photos activity?

Tags: java, android

The Google Plus app contains two separate apps inside the one app. One app is the Google Photos App itself while the other is a Photos app. Launching the Google Plus app is simple since all you need is the Intent action name of the app, but how would you launch the photos app that is inside the G+ app.

Something like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.google.android.apps.plus.photos"));
```

But of coarse this just force closes due to the intent not being found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");  
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.apps.plus.photos"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
    startActivity(intent);
```

or:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus.photos");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Comment: The first one came up with a long list of activities to choose (including photos)

Comment: The second one worked the first time but then stopped working (stopped launching) Thanks for the help tho

Comment: Thank you I figured it out and posted my answer

Comment: doesn't work anymore for android 11

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Oli I was able to modify his first answer to work. All I did was add .setpackage so that the choose from list wont show. Thank you

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");  
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.apps.plus.photos"));
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
        startActivity(intent);
```